# Combining MYSQL queries in php view

Tags: php, mysql

I was given the task of making a web app to replace an excel booking sheet that was constantly locked due to growing number of users. The booking database (of about a hundred possible assets) looks something like this:

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| bookedDate         | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bookedBy           | varchar(256)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| startDate          | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| endDate            | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Equipment1         | varchar(512)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Equipment2         | varchar(512)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ...                |               |      |     |         |       |
| Equipment15        | varchar(512)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

So users can book out up to 15 assets in a booking for a period of 1d-1Y.

On my php page the display view (only booked assets are shown) looks something like this:

```
        <<< << < Prev week  Bookings for week 49 - 2014 Next week > >> >>>
      Monday     Tuesday    Wednesday   Thursday  Friday     Saturday    Sunday
     01/12/2014 02/12/2014 03/12/2014 04/12/2014 05/12/2014 06/12/2014 07/12/2014
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Eq1  | fred                      tom      tom     tom                    harry
Eq4  | tom        tom                                        frank
Eq66 |                                                       tom          tom
...
Eq832|                          harry
```

This all works but the page is very slow. 20-30 sec to generate a page with ~50 assets
The code to pick which assets are displayed (takes about 3 sec) is:

```
function read_Equipment($sDate,$eDate){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT Equipment1 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment2 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment3 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment4 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment5 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment6 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment7 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment8 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment9 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment10 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment11 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment12 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment13 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment14 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' union 
        SELECT Equipment15 FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>'$eDate' 
        order by Equipment1")or die();
    while($ad= mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        if($ad['Equipment1'] != "")
        {
            $rdata[$ad['Equipment1']] = $ad['Equipment1'];
        }
    }
    return($rdata);
}
```

And getting each day code (takes about 120ms, and around 20s in total) looks like this

```
function read_booking($equipment,$sDate,$eDate){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oldDB WHERE startDate<'$sDate' AND endDate>='$eDate' AND (
        Equipment1 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment2 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment3 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment4 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment5 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment6 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment7 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment8 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment9 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment10 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment11 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment12 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment13 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment14 = '$equipment' OR 
        Equipment15 = '$equipment'
        )")or die();
    $rdata = "";
    while($ad = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        if($ad != "")
        {
            $rdata += $ad['ID']." - ";
        }
    }
    return($rdata);
}
```

The code for putting it all together looks like this

```
//$time_i = time at start of the week
$tepp = read_Equipment($sDate,$eDate);
foreach($tepp as $time){
    echo '<tr><th class="booking_time_th">' . $time . '</th>';
    $i = 0;
    while($i < 7){
        $i++;
        $msc=microtime(true);
        $strtmp = read_booking($time,date('Y-m-d', $time_i+($i)*24*3600),date('Y-m-d', $time_i+($i-1)*24*3600));
        echo '<td>'.(microtime(true)-$msc).'s<div class="booking_time_div">
        <div class="booking_time_cell_div" id="div:' . $strtmp . '" onclick="void(0)">' . $strtmp. '</div></div></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

The microtimes are just there to track the progress and dont affect the total length all that much.

So my question is how can I better combine the sql queries so that there are not hundred of little queries (hundreds at 0.1ms total 20-30s)?
Should I be rearranging the database better?

Comment: You certainly can rearrange this better but I don't have time for an example (I'm sure others will give one shortly!) ... however, I'd start with making sure you have indexes set up on every column you might search, which looks like all of them. This will speed things up a LOT

Answer (score 0):

I would personally give each asset an 'id' and label their table as assets. Then I would create a equipment table and the first column in it would be 'asset_id'. 'asset_id' would be a foreign key to the 'id' column in the assets table. This creates a link from a particular asset to any number of rows in the equipment table- effectively removing the current limitation of 15 pieces of equipment. This is an EAV Table structure.

Then again, I would be using Eloquent from Laravel 4 or CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Consider building your systems utilizing a framework.

Edit: Indexes will also speed up your searches. I would index the startDate, endDate, and any fields used in search (currently all equipment fields). However, please note that while this will speed up SELECT queries it will slightly slow down the INSERT queries to this table. Also, if you do switch over to an EAV structure like I described above you can index far fewer columns to achieve the same, faster result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I dont think that I was quiet clear enough with the layout of the database. Assets are equipment that can be booked out. I like your idea of having a separate table for the assets with all assets booked but this table would be 5-10 times larger and slower to search I would think. Will give it a go and see the results. Also looking into frameworks.

Comment: The issue with speed is your repeated queries. Allowing MYSQL to do the searching will actually greatly speed things up even though this new table would have many many more entries. MYSQL is designed to search tables of millions of records. Otherwise, indexing with help slightly.